# Inconsistent Persistence of DataFrames in Spark 1.5

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

We recently switched to Spark 1.5.0 from 1.4.1 and have noticed some inconsistent behavior in persisting DataFrames.

```
df1 = sqlContext.read.parquet("df1.parquet")
df1.count()
```

> 161,100,982

```
df2 = sqlContext.read.parquet("df2.parquet")
df2.count()
```

> 67,498,706

```
join_df = df1.join(df2, "id")
join_df.count()
```

> 160,608,147

```
join_df.write.parquet("join.parquet")
join_parquet = sqlContext.read.parquet("join.parquet")
join_parquet.count()
```

> 67,698,892

```
join_df.write.json("join.json")
join_json = sqlContext.read.parquet("join.json")
join_json.count()
```

> 67,695,663

The first major issue is that there is an order of magnitude difference between the count of the join DataFrame and the persisted join DataFrame.  Secondly, persisting the same DataFrame into 2 different formats yields different results.

Does anyone have any idea on what could be going on here?

Comment: I assume the path not matching is a typo?

Comment: You are not using the same paths

Comment: Yes the paths mismatching is a typo

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem in Spark 1.6.1:

When I created 2 different DataFrames from single RDD and persisted to 2 Parquets, I found out, that Rows in parquets are not the same.

Later I found out that somewhere among definition of pipeline of operations for this RDD, I had rdd.reduceByKey() operation, that returned undeterministic result for multiple calls.

Apparently that for each DataFrame one different reduceByKey() was called and resulted in small differences in some Rows.

Might be something similar in your case.